# I deployed server openlitespeed on Ubuntu 22.04lts and then built the WordPress blog program, but when I access it it shows a 404 error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, openlitespeed

This is the address I visited:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9e9z.png)

Here is the location where the 'index. php' file is stored:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8yJo.png)

This is the root address configured in the openlitespeed backend ->virtual machine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrBcL.png)
In my opinion, the location where I accessed the file is correct. I don't know why I said 404

Additionally, this is done in openlitespeed>Server Configuration>External App:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcvmy.png)
The address inside was written by me following the tutorial, and I am not sure if it is useful or how to determine it

All in all,this is my first attempt to establish a personal website, and I am not very faimiliar with many of its configurations. Therefore, if you need any other information, please let me know

I have changed the address of the 'wordpress ubuntu' folder many times, and then checked multiple times to see if it was a path issue. In a tutorial, it mentioned the value represented by the environment variable of openlitespeed, so I am sure there is no problem accessing the IP address.
I think the problem may be with PHP. I downloaded version 8.2 of PHP separately, but later I completely removed it. I don't know how to fill in the address in the external program configured in Openlitespeed, and I'm not sure if I need to download additional packages for other functions in PHP, such as the 'MySQL php' 'that integrates MySQL with PHP (what is the name?).
I don't know if PHP also has additional packages for integrating Openlitespeed servers, so I removed PHP 8.2 and followed the tutorial as follows:
Installing PHP 8 for OpenLiteSpeed
When we install OpenLiteSpeed, it will automatically install PHP version 7.3 made for OpenLiteSpeed. However, of course, we would like to have an updated version so that we can install PHP 8.0 using the following command:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3zcY.png)

Answer (score 0):

To check the 404 issue, you might also want to share the config of the Listener(with domain mapping part) and the Document root of the Virtual host.

The OpenLiteSpeed web admin still needs PHP 7.3 or PHP 7.4, that's why you saw it is installed by default. Install an additional PHP version won't cause any issues with it.

If you have any other clean VPS, I'd suggest you follow [install-from-one-click-script document](https://docs.openlitespeed.org/installation/script#install-from-one-click-script) to install OpenLiteSpeed + PHP + DataBase + WordPress in one command and see how it's set up. So you will get more know-how about how to set up the Listener, Virtual Host, PHP ..etc.